# c++ overloaded plus operator for dynamic arrays

Tags: c++

I have class which contains a dynamic array I want to overload the plus operator. This is my code: it does not work. The class name TProgram and there is a dynamic array kt and I want to expand the orginal array with another array.

```
TProgram TProgram::operator+(const TProgram &Tv) const {

 int K = 0; 
TProgram Larger;

delete []Larger.Ct;

Larger.kt = new string[Length];


    for(int Y = 0; Y < Length; Y++){


        Larger.kt[K++] = kt[Y];
    }

    for(int X = Tv.Length; X < Length; X++){

           Larger.kt[K++] = Tp.kt[X];
    }

    return Larger;
 }
```

Comment: "It does not work" is a totally inadequate problem description.   Your code reflects several assumptions about what the members of `TProgram` are, and what they mean.   You have provided no such information, so nobody can help.   Read up on how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: `Larger.kt = new string[Length];` ==> `Larger.kt = new string[Length+Tv.Length];` And that second for looks like limits are wrong.That said, best of luck with the rule-of-three issue I hav a feeling will be surfacing, and that right soon.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Back of my head `Tp` is not defined and so is `Length`. Second by the end of the first loop K=Length, therefore in the next loop `Larger.kt[K++]` is accessing a chunk of memory that does not correspond to Larger.kt. I think you should try a debugger on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to change this 3 things:

1. `Larger.kt = new string[Length];` to `Larger.kt = new string[Length + Tv.Length];` because the array will be the sum of the two
2. `int X = Tv.Length;` to `int X = 0;` because you are iterating through another array, so you have to start from the beginning
3. `X < Length` to `X < Tv.Length` because you are iterating through the `Tv`'s array, and not the `*this`'s array

And then i think it should work.
Also I would suggest to create a private constructor that takes a `int size`  and assign a new array to the array pointer inside the class with that size (better if in the initialization list) in order to avoid code like this:

```
TProgram Larger;
delete []Larger.Ct;
Larger.kt = new string[Length + Tv.Length];
```

and instead use code like this:

```
TProgram Larger(Length + Tv.Length);
```